# How load and execute (scoped) script by $.getScript()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to dynamically load script wrapped like this:

```
{
(function () {
    "use strict";

    function myFunction() {
        // code
    }

    myFunction();
})();
}
```

I i use jquery function `$.getScript()` script is loaded, but no executed. (in webmaster tools i can see request and response - script is here with content)

How i can load and automaticly execute script like this?

Comment: Add, as the first line, on its own, in your .js file:  `alert("test")` - does that alert run?

Comment: I was tried this... No.. If i remove wrap `{(function () {}}` alert() works.

Comment: Ok - that confirms it's not the `$.getScript` / url that's the problem but your js.  I suggest you remove the extraneous `{}` wrapper, should then work.

Comment: Yes but i haven't access to this script it is 3rd part (retarget script) which i need execute in modal full of ajax requests... After some of this request is success (after order was send) i have success() function and from there i need load this script and execute...

Answer (score 0):

I was solve this problem with another ajax request **not** to javascript file but to html file (html response) with basic tag `script` with url address. Also with passed some variables into it.

So my html looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var varPassedToScript = 1;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.urlToScript.com/script.js"></script>
```

And it works...

If anybody have better solution - i'm curious